# int[] Vs comparable[] in java, when to use?

Tags: java

While I was implementing Merge Sort, I found this piece of code:

```
    public static void merge(Comparable[] a, int lo, int mid, int hi)
    { // Merge a[lo..mid] with a[mid+1..hi].
        int i = lo, j = mid+1;
        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) // Copy a[lo..hi] to aux[lo..hi].
            aux[k] = a[k];
        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) // Merge back to a[lo..hi].
            if (i > mid) 
                a[k] = aux[j++];
            else if (j > hi )
                a[k] = aux[i++];
            else if (less(aux[j], aux[i]))
                a[k] = aux[j++];
            else 
                a[k] = aux[i++];
     }
```

---

This one merges the sub arrays one by one! But what confuses me is the fact, in the parameter,why is `Comparable[] a` used when this can still be solved using `int[] a` . Does the usage of Comparable add any performance tweak in this case?
From other answers I found,

> Use Comparable if you want to define a default (natural) ordering
>   behaviour of the object in question, a common practice is to use a
>   technical or natural (database?) identifier of the object for this.
>
> Use Comparator if you want to define an external controllable ordering
>   behaviour, this can override the default ordering behaviour.

**The question is**: does the usage of `Comparable[]` improves the efficiency of this code in any bit?

Comment: It's not a difference in performance, it's a difference in where you can use it.

Comment: Are you telling of accessing this from another class?

Comment: no, why would that matter?  It's a question of what arrays you can use it on.

Comment: so should I choose to stick with array instead of comparable in this case?

Comment: that's up to you. Do you have integer arrays you need to sort, or do you have arrays of other Comparable objects to sort?

Comment: The only question here is *what kinds of arrays do you have that need to be sorted.*

Comment: Its just integers that I need to sort!

Comment: Then use the int[] variation.

Comment: I am following Algorithms 4th Edition book, http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/ . Btw is there anyway I can improve the efficiency of this one? Not speaking of the auxilliary space consumed, but the complexity is O(NlogN) and can I reduce the constant C to any lower, any tweaks/suggestions would be really nice! .... And thanks for helping :)

Comment: No, you can't do better than O(n log n), and there's no simple way to reduce the constant factors on merge sort, though Java's built in Arrays.sort uses a very complex but efficient mergesort variant.

Comment: I read that Java uses dual pivot quick sort and Tim sort in the default sort! Would you recommend to choose the Tim sort over Merge sort in all cases where Merge sort is preffered?

Comment: I would recommend blindly using Java's built in sorts, as they're implemented by much smarter people than either of us.

Comment: But would you allow to do that in an Interview? say for a Google interview? If its permitted, then == party time! I mean one liner that beats all manual efforts XD

Comment: I _am_ a Google interviewer, and I expect candidates to write code like they'd write it in the real world, which means using libraries.  Additionally, there is absolutely 100% no way you'd have time to write a Timsort implementation in an interview context.

Comment: So, are you saying it's perfectly alright to use the Arrays.sort() and BinarySearch() methods that are available by default in Java?

Comment: Assuming they're applicable to the problem, sure, though you may get pressed on how you'd implement those methods, or you may find yourself in a situation where you can't use them directly.

Comment: I see! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105074/discussion-between-shaheen-and-louis-wasserman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of `Comparable[]` does not improve the efficiency of the code that you shown at all.

The code that you shown works with any array of objects that are Comparable not only `int`s.

All the difference could be noticed in the `less` method execution, which is not shown in your question but that I assume it is something like `return a.compareTo(b) < 0;`.

If any efficiency difference could be noticed, it would be due to the `compareTo` method implementation of your `Comparable` objects.